# Change tracking while using bilatex-apa results in an error

Tags: biblatex, changes

I am trying to track changes with the [changes package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/changes) while using [biblatex-apa](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa). Now I ran into an error which leaves me clueless...

Here is my example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%bilatex-apa
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,hyperref=false,doi,url]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage{changes} %highlight changes

\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
  @article{foo,
    Author = {Umpt, E. R. and Much, I. and Numo, C.},
    Journal = {A Journal},
    Pages = {802-984},
    Title = {Entitled},
    Volume = {100},
    Year = {2000}},
  @inbook{bar,
    Author = {Bob},
    Booktitle = {Online wub},
    Editor = {John},
    Pages = {180-202},
    Publisher = {Gotham city},
    Title = {This is some title},
    Year = {2002}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}


\begin{document}

\added{\textcite{foo} wtf.}
\deleted{test \parencite{foo,bar}}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is the error message:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\UL@stop ...z@ \else \UL@putbox \fi \else \egroup 
                                                  \egroup \UL@putbox \fi \if...
l.38 \deleted{test \parencite{foo,bar}}
                                       .
? 
! Emergency stop.
\UL@stop ...z@ \else \UL@putbox \fi \else \egroup 
                                                  \egroup \UL@putbox \fi \if...
l.38 \deleted{test \parencite{foo,bar}}
                                       .
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I'm working with pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011) on Debian Squeeze and I updates all packages ;).

Comment: Your example compiles without error for me. Try to delete all auxiliary files and compile again.

Comment: Same here, no errors.

Comment: Sorry, I reduced my original code too much... Now the code example should work. It seem that there have to be three authors in the first reference to get the error.

Comment: I don't get an error message when running your updated MWE (running TeXLive2011 and all the latest packages).

Comment: @Mico With three authors in the first reference, I can confirm the error for `biblatex-apa`. (The example works fine with the `authoryear` style.)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, I do, and yes, everything's up-to-date.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Did you removed the old bib-file in your example folder. However the error based on expansions problem by using the package ulem. You can simple create a `\def\testhere#1{\sout{#1}}` whereby `\sout{test {\parencite{foo,bar}}}` works and `\testhere{test \parencite{foo,bar}}` not.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: no, I didn't (I forgot that filecontents doesn't overwrite its contents if the file exists). Now that I've done it, the error is there ;-)

Comment: @deboerk: The first way that will work \deleted{test \mbox{\parencite{foo,bar}}} However I know it isn't a good solution. I will check it out. This can be found in the documentation of `ulem` (search cite)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem based on the package `ulem` which is loaded by the package `changes` to highlight your changes.

In the documentation of `ulem` you can find the following paragraph

> Text produced by expansion of a command (macro) is boxed too, but `\\`, `\` , and `\-` still work properly in the expansion text so that while

```
  \newcommand\iff{if and only if}` ... `\uline{\iff}`
```

> prevents stretching and line-breaking between words, the alternative

```
\newcommand\iff{if\ and\ only\ if}` ... `\uline{\iff}`
```

> allows stretching and line-breaking. There is a remaining problem though: the `\` (backslash-space) between words closes a group and any local assignments will be lost, in particular, font changes and color changes.
>
> This loss of local assignments will break some other standard commands, (e.g., `\cite`) which produce multiple ‘words’ using local assignments. The way to protect such commands is to bury them in an `\mbox`: `\emph{every\-one agrees~\mbox{\cite{you,me}}.}`

So the easiest way in your example is using `\deleted{test \mbox{\parencite{foo,bar}}`. However `\mbox{}` doesn't allow any line breaks of your `\cite` command.

An alternative "strike out packages" `soul` will also fail if you use the command `\parencite`.

However I think you can use the code of Andrew Stacey (which can be improved) to highlight your text:
[How to “highlight” text/formals with tikz?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA5I3.png)

Without changing the internals of the package `changes` you can use:

```
\long\def\sout#1{\highlight[highlighter width=.4pt,highlighter colour=black]{#1}}
```

A complete example which includes the linked idea is (you must compile twice to get the correct output):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
%bilatex-apa
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,hyperref=false,doi,url,]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage[normalem,normalbf]{ulem} %highlight changes
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
  @article{foo,
   Author = {Aumpt, E. R. and Much, I. and Numo, C.},
    Journal = {A Journal},
    Pages = {802-984},
    Title = {Entitled},
    Volume = {100},
    Year = {2000}},
  @inbook{bar,
    Author = {Bob},
    Booktitle = {Online wub},
    Editor = {John},
    Pages = {180-202},
    Publisher = {Gotham city},
    Title = {This is some title},
    Year = {2002}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}
\makeatletter

%
% Highlighter code
%

\tikzset{%
  remember picture with id/.style={%
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    save picture id=#1,
  },
  save picture id/.code={%
    \edef\pgf@temp{#1}%
    \immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
      \noexpand\savepointas{\pgf@temp}{\pgfpictureid}}%
  }
}

\def\savepointas#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{pic}{%
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@#1}{%
    \pgfpointorigin
  }{%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname}\save@orig@pic%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\pgfpictureid}\save@this@pic%
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@this@pic}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@orig@pic}%
  \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
  \advance\pgf@y by -\pgf@ya
  }%
}

\newcounter{highlight}
\newcommand{\hlstart}{\tikz[remember picture with id=hlstart\the\value{highlight},baseline=-0.7ex];\hl@start}
\newcommand{\hlend}{\tikz[remember picture with id=hlend\the\value{highlight},baseline=-0.7ex];\hl@end\stepcounter{highlight}}
\newcommand{\fdstart}{\tikz[remember picture with id=hlstart\the\value{highlight},baseline=-0.7ex];\fd@start}
\newcommand{\fdend}{\tikz[remember picture with id=hlend\the\value{highlight},baseline=-0.7ex];\fd@end\stepcounter{highlight}}
\newcommand{\vlstart}{\tikz[remember picture with id=hlstart\the\value{highlight},baseline=-1em];\vl@start}
\newcommand{\vlend}{\tikz[remember picture with id=hlend\the\value{highlight},baseline=0.3ex];\vl@end\stepcounter{highlight}}

\newcommand{\hl@start}[1][]{%
  \hl@draw{highlighter}{#1}{\the\value{highlight}}}

\newcommand{\hl@end}{}

\newcommand{\fd@start}[1][]{%
  \def\fd@args{#1}}

\newcommand{\fd@end}{\def\@tempa{\hl@draw{fader}}\expandafter\@tempa\expandafter{\fd@args}{\the\value{highlight}}\def\fd@args{}}

\newcommand{\vl@start}[1][]{%
  \vl@draw{highlighter}{#1}{\the\value{highlight}}}

\newcommand{\vl@end}{}


\def\hl@sets{%
  \edef\hl@sx{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef\hl@sy{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\def\hl@sete{%
  \edef\hl@ex{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef\hl@ey{\the\pgf@y}%
}

\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{

\def\page@node{
  \path (current page.south east)
      ++(-\beamer@rightmargin,\footheight)
  node[
    minimum width=\textwidth,
    minimum height=\textheight,
    anchor=south east
  ] (page) {};
}

}{

  \def\page@node{
    \path (current page.north west)
    ++(\hoffset + 1in + \oddsidemargin + \leftskip,\voffset + 1in + \topmargin + \headheight + \headsep)
    node[
      minimum width=\textwidth - \leftskip - \rightskip,
      minimum height=\textheight,
      anchor=north west
    ] (page) {};
  }

}

\newcommand{\hl@draw}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
  \page@node
  \tikzset{#2,highlight=#1,every path/.append style={highlight=#1}}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@width}{\the\pgflinewidth - 1pt}%
  \coordinate (hlstart) at (pic cs:hlstart#3);
  \coordinate (hlend) at (pic cs:hlend#3);
  \tikz@scan@one@point\hl@sets(pic cs:hlstart#3)
  \tikz@scan@one@point\hl@sete(pic cs:hlend#3)
  \ifdim\hl@sy=\hl@ey\relax
  \draw (hlstart) -- (hlend);
  \else
  \draw (hlstart) -- (hlstart -| page.east);
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@sy}{\hl@sy -\hl@width}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@ey}{\hl@ey +\hl@width}%
  \loop\ifdim\hl@sy>\hl@ey\relax
  \draw (0,\hl@sy -| page.west) -- (0,\hl@sy -| page.east);
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@sy}{\hl@sy -\hl@width}%
  \repeat
  \draw (hlend -| page.west) -- (hlend);
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\vl@draw}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
  \page@node
  \tikzset{#2,highlight=#1,every path/.append style={highlight=#1}}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@width}{\the\pgflinewidth - 1pt}%
  \coordinate (hlstart) at (pic cs:hlstart#3);
  \coordinate (hlend) at (pic cs:hlend#3);
  \tikz@scan@one@point\hl@sets(pic cs:hlstart#3)
  \tikz@scan@one@point\hl@sete(pic cs:hlend#3)
  \ifdim\hl@sx=\hl@ex\relax
  \draw (hlstart) -- (hlend);
  \else
  \draw (hlstart) -- (hlstart |- page.south);
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@sx}{\hl@sx -\hl@width}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@ex}{\hl@ex +\hl@width}%
  \loop\ifdim\hl@sx>\hl@ex\relax
  \draw (\hl@sx,0 |- page.north) -- (\hl@sx,0 |- page.south);
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@sx}{\hl@sx -\hl@width}%
  \repeat
  \draw (hlend |- page.north) -- (hlend);
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\tikzset{%
  highlight/.default=highlighter,
  highlight/.style={
    color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/#1 colour},
    line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/#1 width},
    line cap=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/#1 cap},
    opacity=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/#1 opacity},
  },
  highlighter colour/.initial=yellow,
  highlighter width/.initial=12pt,
  highlighter cap/.initial=butt,
  highlighter opacity/.initial=1,
  fader colour/.initial=gray,
  fader width/.initial=12pt,
  fader cap/.initial=butt,
  fader opacity/.initial=.5,
}

\newcommand{\highlight}[2][]{%
\hlstart[#1]#2\hlend}

\newcommand{\fade}[2][]{%
\fdstart[#1]#2\fdend}

\newcommand{\vhighlight}[2][]{%
\vlstart[#1]#2\vlend}


\long\def\sout#1{\highlight[highlighter width=.4pt,highlighter colour=black]{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\added{\textcite{foo} wtf.}   \deleted{test \parencite{foo,bar}}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}




\documentclass[varwidth,border=10,]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%bilatex-apa
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,hyperref=false,doi,url,]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage[normalem,normalbf]{ulem} %highlight changes
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
  @article{foo,
   Author = {Aumpt, E. R. and Much, I. and Numo, C.},
    Journal = {A Journal},
    Pages = {802-984},
    Title = {Entitled},
    Volume = {100},
    Year = {2000}},
  @inbook{bar,
    Author = {Bob},
    Booktitle = {Online wub},
    Editor = {John},
    Pages = {180-202},
    Publisher = {Gotham city},
    Title = {This is some title},
    Year = {2002}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\DeclareDocumentCommand \Changes@Markup@Deleted { m }
{%
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \sout{ #1 } }
\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\Changes@optiondeletedmarkup}{none}}{#1}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\Changes@optiondeletedmarkup}{uline}}{\uline{#1}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\Changes@optiondeletedmarkup}{uuline}}{\uuline{#1}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\Changes@optiondeletedmarkup}{uwave}}{\uwave{#1}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\Changes@optiondeletedmarkup}{dashuline}}{\dashuline{#1}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\Changes@optiondeletedmarkup}{dotuline}}{\dotuline{#1}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\Changes@optiondeletedmarkup}{sout}}{\sout{ \l_tmpa_tl }}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\Changes@optiondeletedmarkup}{xout}}{\xout{#1}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\Changes@optiondeletedmarkup}{bf}}{\textbf{#1}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\Changes@optiondeletedmarkup}{it}}{\textit{#1}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\Changes@optiondeletedmarkup}{sl}}{\textsl{#1}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\Changes@optiondeletedmarkup}{em}}{\emph{#1}}{}%
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
    \begin{document}
    \sout{test {\parencite{foo,bar}}}

    \added{\textcite{foo} wtf.}
    \deleted{test \parencite{foo,bar}}.

    \printbibliography

    \end{document}
```

The result will be

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! This solution looks quite complex. Unfortunately it doesn't work if the article has three authors: `{Umpt, E. R. and Much, I. and Numo, C.}`

Comment: @deboerk: I can't test it at the moment. However today at the evening I will refresh my answer.

Comment: @deboerk: The first way that will work `\deleted{test \mbox{\parencite{foo,bar}}}` However I know it isn't a good solution. I will check it out.